Apache POI : Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
I'm trying to replace some words in word document on the same file.
public class WordEdit {
    static String DocX;
    static String DocX2;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocX = "C:\\Users\\aneesh.shaik\\Downloads\\I&TF-0206-2024.docx";
        DocX2 = "D:\\Automation\\Files\\I&TF-0206-2024.docx";
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(DocX));
        for (XWPFTable tbl : doc.getTables()) {
               for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
                  for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                     for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                          String text = r.getText(0);
                          if (text != null && text.contains("Aneesh423")) {
                            text = text.replace("Aneesh423", "Aneesh");
                            System.out.println("find 2");
                            r.setText(text,0);
                          }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
        doc.write(new FileOutputStream(DocX)); // Getting error on this line
        doc.close();        
    }
}

If I write it on DocX2 file location, then its working properly. But if I want to write it on same document on DocX file location, then getting error.
Please help to resolve this issue.

You can save effort and pain to the eye by using single forward slashes in Windows paths

Always use a temp file to write and rename to the intended name afterwards.

The code line XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(DocX)); creates the XWPFDocument by opening the file behind DocX and let the file stay open. That saves a little bit random access memory. But of course nothing can be written to an open file.
If you would use XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(DocX));, then this creates the XWPFDocument by reading the content of the file behind DocX using the FileInputStream. The file does not stay open and the FileOutputStream can write into that same file.
